# cURL - 404 error when trying to POST a file

Tags: curl

Forgive my Linux n00bishness, I'm only just starting out! I'm trying to POST a file to a Windows web listener using cURL but am receiving an error that I haven't been able to find an explanation for online. I've never used cURL before (and am very new to Linux in general) so I don't know where to look for the issue. Here's what I've done so far:

- Navigated to the file directory `/home/user/Documents`
- Used the command `curl --form "fileupload=@mesh.pcap" http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (the file is obviously a pcap file, and the listener is being accessed by IP, simply trying to push the file to any location on the target)

And I receive the following message in the terminal:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Now I'm doing this all based on the cURL manpage, but have no idea if I'm doing it right at all, so if this doesn't even make sense please explain why and I'll do my best to clarify or try whatever suggestions you may have. I think I'm on the right track but the 404 error is confusing me and there is no file actually being transferred. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Some context... Basically I have a pcap file on the Linux box that I want to send to the web listener to be parsed. I don't necessarily need the file itself, as long as the data comes across one way or another. I'm trying to simulate something that a contractor is developing for us, my part is being able to parse the data from the pcap. He said he's sending it through cURL, so I thought I'd set up a little mock environment for testing purposes so we don't have to have a fully-running system before I can do my end of the task.

Comment: Can you access `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` from a browser?

Comment: I can from any other PC (the Ubuntu box is CLI-only), and the web listener confirms receiving any other type of information I try to send it, but does not receive anything from the cURL command.